# Turing Machines/ Turing Completeness

Tags: turing-complete, turing-machines

I was reading the ethereum white paper and I came up with the term Turing-Complete. I did some research and I found out this is a whole mathematical theory. How can I start learning about Turing-Machines and Turing Completeness on a technical level. I don't care about the connection with ethereum i just want to understand the scientific part. I mean with an intro to technical level escalation. I googled this and I found general powerpoints/pdfs but that's not what I am looking for. I decided to ask here(for guidance/textbooks) cause I am pretty sure there are experts here that work on this topic. Sorry for the general-type question. I'm just a guy that loves mathematics and cryptography trying to understand how to world functions.

Kind Regards,
Nick

Comment: I appreciate your interest on the topic, as it is dear to my heart as well, though it is not something that can be explained in an answer of 300 words or less.  There are volumes of books written on this topic.  I would encourage you to learn more, and come back with a slightly more specific question.  ;)

Comment: I have a copy of The Annotated Turing which I found fascinating: https://www.amazon.com/Annotated-Turing-Through-Historic-Computability/dp/0470229055/ref=sr_1_1/133-2755383-6988058?ie=UTF8&qid=1518103035&sr=8-1&keywords=the+annotated+turing&dpID=51du7ChkDML&preST=_SY344_BO1,204,203,200_QL70_&dpSrc=srch

Comment: http://fuuu.be/polytech/INFOF408/Introduction-To-The-Theory-Of-Computation-Michael-Sipser.pdf